# Azure App Service issue with uploading large files: Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, iis, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

I have an AngularJS based web interface, sending a zip file to my `ApiController`. There I'm receiving the file:

```
public async Task<UploadImportPackageResponse> Package()
{
    var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
    await this.Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
    var file = provider.Contents.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name == "\"file\"");
```

This works perfectly fine on my dev machine, on our local test server, but NOT on our Azure App Service staging site.

On Azure it throws the following error:

> **Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not complete.**

```
  System.IO.IOException:
  at System.Net.Http.Formatting.Parsers.MimeMultipartBodyPartParser+<ParseBuffer>d__0.MoveNext (System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
  at System.Net.Http.HttpContentMultipartExtensions+<MultipartReadAsync>d__8.MoveNext (System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
  at System.Net.Http.HttpContentMultipartExtensions+<ReadAsMultipartAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext (System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
  at Test.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers.ImportController+<Package>d__2.MoveNext (Test.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions+<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext (System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
  at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext (System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
  at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult+<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext (System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
  at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult+<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext (System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
```

This is what I've figured out so far:

1. A 1.5 MB file uploads fine, but a 12 MB file doesn't. (with `maxRequestLength="256000"` & `maxAllowedContentLength="262144000"`)
2. I used Charles Proxy to capture a request that caused the error on Azure and re-executed it against my local machine, where it caused no errors. So I'm confident it's a server side issue. Not a client side issue.

**My best guess is that the server cuts the request short.** But I have no idea why, or what configuration to change to address this issue.

Comment: Do you enable remote debugging on your Azure Web App to troubleshoot on server side?

Comment: how long does the upload take for the 12 MB file? are you on a slow connection by any chance?

Comment: Maybe two minutes.  But I increased the timeout already, and didn't make a difference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking to the Azure support, they mentioned that they had fixed a bug like this in their production code, so I went through all my relevant Microsoft nuget packages and realized that MS had released a new version of Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi (and related packages Client, Core, HelpPage & WebHost)

So a `Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi` did the trick for me.

So the short answer is:

**Make sure you have version `5.2.3` or higher of `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi` installed.**